# json in field or second table? php laravel mysql ecommerce

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Currently I have 2 tables:

```
Orders:
id
user_id
p_number
city
status

Order_details:
id
order_id
prod_id
amount
```

Is it better to keep 2 tables OR remove order_details and keep info about products in 1st table in json format: {"prod_id":amount}?

Comment: Hope this makes your decision obvious. What happens if one order has 10 details or 100 details? Or 1,000 details

Comment: Because I have never used json in my tables and I don't know which option is better

Comment: having a child table is better. it will be hasMany relationship

Comment: @RiggsFolly then i will have json like this: {"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount,"p_id":amount...}

Comment: And then when you want to know _who purchased a `left handed widget` in January 2017?_ What do you do then??

Comment: @RiggsFolly then i'll cry xD Thanks, I got it. You can answer and i'll accept it (:

Comment: Then when you come up against the _Row Size Limit of 65K_ What do you do then

Comment: @Batmannn you need to use Many to Many relationship here (each order can have many products, each product can be in many orders). Keep all order data in a single table, and pivot table will have `order_id`, `prod_id`, `quantity`.

Comment: :) Database design is often as much about _How do I want to process my data once I have collected it_ as it is about striving for _4th Normal Form_

Comment: Try get data from one table and from two tables? And check the time and see which query was faster.